# How do I access scope created by ng-form directive?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have this code.

```
<ng-form name="section_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="section in app.sections">
    {{section_$index}}
</ng-form>
```

I want to know for example if section is valid etc. Like {{ section_1.$valid }}.

So how do I access the scope created by ng-form when its name is dynamic based on the $index value?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Got it.

What I did

```
<form name="s.form">
    <ng-form name="section_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="section in app.sections">
        {{s.form['section_'+$index]}}
    </ng-form>
</form>
```